# Copy Specific Array Elements

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I need to copy specific elements from an array to a new array. For example:
An array of Fruits includes apples and oranges in it, I want to get only apples from it to a new array called Apples.

Thank you.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Create a List, iterate the array, add apples to the List, call List.toArray().

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of `instanceof` operator to check if a fruit is an Apple. After that simply do an iteration over the array adding the selected elements to another array.

Answer (score 2):

All in psuedo code:

the first thing you may do:

```
Fruit[] oArray = ....;
int noOfApple = 0;

for each Fruit f in oArray {
  if (f is apple) {
    noOfApple++;
  }
}

Fruit[] newArray = new Fruit[noOfApple];

int index = 0;
for each Fruit f in oArray {
  if (f is apple) {
    newArray[index++] = f;
  }
}
```

well, because you are explicitly creating the new array, so you have to find out the size before you can actually create the new array.  To make it easier, you can do something like

```
List<Fruit> newFruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
for each Fruit f in oArray {
  if (f is apple) {
    newFruits.add(f);
  }
}
Fruit[] newArray = newFruits.toArray();
```

I think the hints should already be more than enough

If you want to do something even cooler, try to use Guava.  You can do something like (most of the code are actual, with a bit psuedo code):

```
Fruit[] result = 
  Iterables.filter(Array.asList(oArray), 
                   new Predicate<Fruit>(){
                     @Override
                     boolean apply(Fruit f) { return (f is apple);}
                   })
           .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using ArrayList. With ArrayList, you can dynamically add items to it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.size(); i++)
{
  if (fruits.get(i) instanceof apple)
     apples.add(fruits.get(i));
}
```

And if you still want an array of apples. `Apple[] arrayOfApples = apples.ToArray();`

Comment: Why not `for (Fruit fruit : fruits)`?

Comment: Not to annoy you but fruits will be empty :P, and yes use the foreach it is safer, and in Java we usually put braces behind the for loop

Comment: @Christo I think it's assumed that it's prefilled

Comment: I'm making a lot of assumptions here...

Comment: I know ... but in that case do not write `= new ArrayList<Fruits>();`, also you cannot affect a list of fruits to a list of apples :), but I agree with the method details omitted

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy I like `foreach` better. And what do you mean by "we usually put braces behind the `for` loop?"

Comment: @edmastermind29 i mean something like `for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {`, also one more detail use the generic type of the left-hand side `List<Fruits>` instead of `ArrayList<Fruits>`

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy removed any assumed code (ie, `= new ArrayList<Fruits>();`)...just displaying only the logic behind what to do.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Okay, is that best practice just for `for` loops or Java in general? And thanks.

Comment: @edmastermind29 The foreach loop introduced in Java 5 is safer than the low level for loop as it encapsulates the index. The less code you have the less you can mess up. For the formatting, it seems to be the one used for JDK code and by most Java IDE. The other style is mostly C/C++ or some other languages.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy I use foreach in C# and I agree with you that there is less code involved. I've always used the formatting above because the one you mention feels like javascript, but if it is best practice, no arguments from me.